# WPF SplashScreen class can not locate the embedded image

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

I'm trying to display `splash screen for my WPF application`. Based on some condition I have to load one of two images I have created. So i have to use [SplashScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen.aspx) class instead of setting a [static image as flashscreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656886.aspx). Which is easy and works in my case.

I'm doing something like following,(*I have set the both images as Embedded Resource*)

```
string splashImage = string.Empty;
if (Condition)
  {
    splashImage = "ApplicationType1.png";
  }
else
  {
    splashImage = "ApplicationType2.png";
  }

SplashScreen screen = new SplashScreen(splashImage);
screen.Show(true);
```

Which gives me exeception,

> Cannot locate resource ApplicationType1.png

Comment: where have you added the images in project hierarchy?

Comment: where are `ApplicationType1.png` and `ApplicationType2.png` sitting in your project? maybe you need a relative path to get them ...

Comment: @nit Under Images folder

Comment: then you will have to access them as "images/ApplicationType1.png" in the resource not directly

Comment: @nit I have tried that, No luck.

Comment: Also, build action should be Resource, not Embedded Resource.

Comment: @KentBoogaart Tried that as well, didnt work.

Comment: can you share the resources you have created and where have you added them?

Comment: you might have to set the  ImageSource as "/ProjectName;component/images/ApplicationType1.png"

Comment: @Omribitan No that didnt work.

Comment: Have you tried [Pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)?. something like 
pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/images/ApplicationType1.png

Comment: @Omribitan Just tried Pack URI, No luck.

Comment: is the executing code in the same hirarchy as the images folder? if not you need to use `..` to get to that hirarchy. for example if your'e under `MainModule` folder you'll need `"../images/ApplicationType1.png` assuming `MainModule` and `images` are at the same hirarchy level ...

Comment: @Omribitan Image is in the same hirarchy as execution folder. Thanks for the suggestions mate :)

Comment: @nit Problem was with the .png i have added. it works with .jpg. Still no clue why it didnt work. because splash screen supports .png as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i figured it out,

Problem was with the `.png` image i have added. Still i have no clue why it couldn't load that specific image. I just got the `.jpg` image and it works fine.

And it works with both build actions `Embedded Resource` or `Resource`

Comment: I had this issue as well. I re-saved the .png. Some editing tool I had used had added transparency and I think that was causing the load to fail. Not that the resource couldn't be found as the error message says, but that the format is wrong.